# Can't remove or unmount loop device on Debian

Tags: debian, mount, devices, loop-device

I have a loop device which shows up when I do `losetup --all` that I have been unable to remove.

So, I basically got myself into this issue because a created a raw image of a microSD card and then I used `kpartx` to mount the partitions contained within the image.

The commands that I initially used to mount the image and partitions were as follows:-

```
user@server:~$ sudo kpartx -arsv '/path/to/microsd.img';
add map loop1p1 (254:12): 0 819168 linear 7:14 32
add map loop1p2 (254:13): 0 29351936 linear 7:14 819200
user@server:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop1p2 /mnt/sdimage1p2;
user@server:~$ ls -alh /mnt/sdimage1p2;
```

As this was just a test I then wanted to unmount remove the loop device, so I ran the following commands, I have tried running them in different orders so see if my ordering was the problem.

```
sudo umount /mnt/sdimage1p2;
sudo dmsetup info;
sudo losetup --detach /dev/mapper/loop1p1;
sudo losetup --detach /dev/mapper/loop1p2;
sudo losetup --detach /dev/mapper/loop1;
sudo dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/loop1p1;
sudo dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/loop1p2;
sudo kpartx -dsv '/path/to/microsd.img';
sudo losetup --all;
```

Also `dmsetup info` returns `no devices found`.

But `losetup --all` returns the following:-

```
/dev/loop1: [2082]:1809010 (/path/to/microsd.img)
```

I have also tried the following commands which return nothing.

```
fuser -c /dev/loop1;
fuser -f /dev/loop1;
```

I have also tried `lsof | grep loop` this returns the output below.

```
loop1     10693                   root  cwd       DIR                8,2           4096                    2 /
loop1     10693                   root  rtd       DIR                8,2           4096                    2 /
loop1     10693                   root  txt   unknown                                                        /proc/10693/exe
```

But I was unsure what to do with the above information, I did try `kill -9 10693` but that didn't work, the PID `10693` does show up in `htop`.

```
user@server:~$ ps -fp 10693
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     10693     2  0 08:17 ?        00:00:00 [loop1]
```

Comment: Well, what is that PID 10693? What does `ps -fp 10693` say?

Comment: @telcoM I added the output to the original question thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the PPID is 2, this process 10693 is a kernel process, and that explains why your `kill -9` did not work.

You said you have tried `sudo losetup --detach /dev/mapper/loop1`. That was almost but not quite correct: try `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1` instead. But it only works *after* the partition loop devices have already been removed, so if you tried it before your `sudo losetup --detach /dev/mapper/loop1p*` commands, it would have failed.

The fewest commands to achieve the removal of the loop devices would probably have been something like:

```
sudo umount /mnt/sdimage1p2
sudo kpartx -d /dev/loop1
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1
```

exactly in this order.

Comment: see my original question, I have tried that also, it may of been missed in the sea of commands, but it is the 3rd command after the one you said I tried.

Actually I just tried the command you said and it worked!

So why did `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1` work but `sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop1` didn't.

Comment: The ordering of the commands is important: you must first remove the partition loop devices (`loop1pN`), only after that you can remove the whole-disk loop device. `sudo umount /mnt/sdimage1p2; sudo kpartx -d /dev/loop1; sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1` might have been a more optimal way to do what you were after.

Comment: Yeah I figured the ordering was important, I was a bit unsure as to what the order should be, and unfortunately trial and error didn't get me as far as I would have liked.